# How to force a .unityfile to text for Instance ID comparison using c#

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I am trying to force a .unity file, the scene files which unity uses to text. It is possible to change this in the editor for read out purposes by going into the edit > project settings > editor and setting the asset serialization to force text.

You will get something like

```
--- !u!1 &1116311739
GameObject:
m_Component:
- 4: {fileID: 1116311741}
- 114: {fileID: 1116311740}
m_Name: Object1
--- !u!114 &1116311740
MonoBehaviour:
m_Script: {fileID: 11500000, guid: 522cee70d3f794241885ec229977790f, type: 3}
anotherObject: {fileID: 107191716}
--- !u!4 &1116311741
```

But I can't seem to find out how to reach this through my c# script.

So how can I force a .unity scene file to text using a c# script so I can compare ID's?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can't. It's a serialization settings and affect all assets in the project.
Actually it isn't possible to modify Project Settings by script either.

In addition, `guid` is different from `instance id`.

`Guid` uniquely identify an asset in the asset database. It's stored in the asset relative meta file. You can get the relative `string` representation using an asset path and [AssetDatabase.AssetPathToGUID](http://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/AssetDatabase.AssetPathToGUID.html). (Never tried but I don't think this work with scenes, I maybe wrong though)

`Instance Ids` are associated to every runtime asset derived from [UnityEngine.Object](http://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Object.html), and are guaranteed to be unique in the current running session. Scenes don't have an instance id.

---

EDIT

`SerializedFields` (public variables) belong to `MonoBehaviors` (or `ScriptableObjects`), not to scenes. Every object saved into a scene is identified in the scene yaml files using an id (which make sense only within the scene file it self AFAIK).

As example: `--- !u!1 &1116311739` this is the number id used to identify the object in the file you posted. If another gameobject instance reference that GameObject in the scene file will be recorded that number.

For example if there is a MonoBehavior with a serialized field `foobar` referencing that `GameObject` somewhere(under the relative MonoBehavior entry) in the scene file you will find a row

```
 foobar: {fileID: 1116311739}
```

If the referenced object is stored in an asset (for example a prefab), then you will also find the reference to that:

```
 foobar: {fileID: 100002, guid: 1d84e00e1dda18b4981a2d42e72874d1, type: 2}
```

It's just a quick example, there isn't much documentation on this topic but you can find something [here](http://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/YAMLSceneExample.html).

I don't think unity at the moment offers any script facilities for reading the scene's yaml files. If you really need to access those files, you need to do that by your own.

Comment: Would the AssetDatabase.AssetPathToGUID. allow me to read the public assigned variables of the object within the scene ? Or can I really only obtain the GUID of objects through this ?

Comment: No. AssetPathToGUID take a path (in the file system) and returns the gui relative to the given asset if any. " allow me to read the public assigned variables of the object within the scene": I don't understand this. could you clarify a little bit? What exactly do you want to do?

Comment: In unity you can use public variables, within a scene (.unity file) you can drag and drop items on these variables. I want to read out the assigned value of that public variable out of the .unity file through a editor script, so I can determine whether it is used or .not.

Comment: The update is very use full, Ill dig into the yaml files and see how far I can get. Thank you very much.